# I can't access my intranet password server from Tor

Tags: configuration

We have an intranet password server but I can't access it from Tor. The Add-on installed pops up with a request for host address and port. I enter the host name and the port and then get a message that "https://hostname:port" (hostname is my local server name and port is its access port) is unreachable. There is no way to put a permission. I can access it OK from a Firefox version 56 browser after having added the correct permissions. Please help

Answer (score 1):

Tor Browser will not allow this, because it could be used to deanonymize you. Your intranet server is only available on the intranet, if it's not routable from the internet then Tor will not be able to communicate with it.

There is no fix for this, and any "fix" would be bad for Tor's anonymity, since access to the intranet cannot be achieved over Tor it would involve making connections outside of Tor, which Tor Browser goes to great lengths to try and prevent.

The solution would be to use Tor and Tor Browser distinct from intranet access.